# Squarespace:query Parent Scope

Tags: squarespace

I'm using Squarespace's Developer Platform.

Is there a way to break out of the squarespace:query tag's scope? Inside of the tags, it seems impossible to reference any keys/values/variables on the outside of it. I want to display only a specific collection item's content based on a variable from the page being built (the page using squarespace:query).

Example snippet:

```
<div class="infosection" data-info-section="Series">
<p id="seriesTitle">
{customContent.seriesName}
</p>
<p id="seriesBlurb">
<squarespace:query collection="series-1" category="{customContent.seriesName}">
{# No apparent way to break out of query tag scope, have to ghetto rig a filter with 'category' attribute}
<script>console.log({@|json-pretty})</script>
{.section items.0}
{excerpt}
{.end}
</squarespace:query>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're correct that there is no way to get access to data from outside the query. Similarly, there's no way to pass data into the query (via the `var` directive, for example) from outside of it. It's unfortunate because that often would be the best use-case for the `var` directive, but it just doesn't work that way.

So, using a query with a tag and/or category filter is indeed the only way to do it within the JSON-T template system (except for JSONP requests, see below).

The other alternative is to use JavaScript. Nearly every page on your Squarespace site can requested as JSON data via the added parameters `/series-1?format=json`. So, you could make an AJAX request and use the data that way. Or, make a JSONP request to the URL like:

```
<script>
  function mycallbackFn(jsonData) {
    // do stuff with the jsonData here. You could even build your own template literal if you only need to support modern browsers.
  }
</script>

<script src="/{fullUrl}/?format=json&callback=mycallbackFn"></script>
```

In theory you could insert that right into your JSON-T. If resorting to JavaScript, the AJAX approach is likely more maintainable, however. The content would also not be easily indexed, being dynamically added.

In some cases, an alternative approach is to hard-code all the variations into the query like the following example. This likely doesn't help in your case, but I include this because it is sometimes an approach for issues related to yours:

(This example assumes items have only a single category assigned.)

```
<squarespace:query collection="mycollectionslug" limit="99">
{.repeated section items}
  {.repeated section categories}
    {.equal?:@:"My Category 1"}
      <p>Content specific to my category 1.</p>
    {.end}
    {.or equal?:@:"My Category 2"}
      <p>Content specific to my category 2.</p>
    {.end}
    {# etc.}
  {.end}
{.end
</squarespace:query>
```

In summary, however, the limitation you're running into regarding squarespace:query and scope is a common one and can only be worked around, usually in some less-than-ideal manner, as you've discovered.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried using a var directive prior to and was surprised it didn't work. I like the idea of using the url though. Hopefully Squarespace will give the Developer platform a little more control in the future so we don't have to constantly hack our way through seemingly simple tasks.